# Load Static doesn't work when I try to implement Bootstrap theme with Django

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, web-development-server

So I downloaded a bootstrap theme called "modern-business" and I tried to merge it with my django app. This is how it looks:
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQtCW.png)

This is how it should look:
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf1qg.png)

I was able to figure out that my load static isn't working, because I tried to display some pictures on the webpage and I was able to do that when they were in the same folder as index.hmtl file.
But they did not work when I put the images in the static file.
This is how I am writing it. for the css, images and the js src lines

*link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"*

I have included {% load static %} as well
My static file is in /mainproject/recordmgmt/static

This is my first time trying to merge django and bootstrap and also the first time using django.
I think there I am making a mistake with adding the correct path,but I could be wrong. Let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Show us the code in your views.py

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    title = 'Welcome: This is the Home Page'
    context = {
    "title": title,
    }
    return render(request, "home.html",context)

def list_records(request):
    header = 'Records'
    form = StockSearchForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset = record.objects.all()
    context = {
    "header": header,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "form": form,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        queryset = record.objects.filter(item_name__icontains=form['item_name'].value()
                                        )

        #This part here is to export to csv using the same search button
        if form['export_to_CSV'].value() == True:
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Data.csv"'
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            #change these according to the data we have in the database, these are the heading for the csv file 
            #find a better way to do this (no hardcoding)
            writer.writerow(['CATEGORY', 'ITEM NAME', 'Created By'])
            instance = queryset
            for stock in instance:
                writer.writerow([stock.category, stock.item_name, stock.created_by])
            return response
    

        context = {
        "form": form,
        "header": header,
        "queryset": queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "list_records.html",context)



def add_items(request):
    form = StockCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "title": "Add Record",
    }
    return render(request, "add_items.html", context)




def update_items(request, pk):
    queryset = record.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = RecordUpdateForm(instance=queryset)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecordUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=queryset)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Updated')
            return redirect('/list_records')

    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'add_items.html', context)


def delete_items(request, pk):
    queryset = record.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        queryset.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully Deleted')
        return redirect('/list_records')
    return render(request, 'delete_items.html')


def stock_detail(request, pk):
    queryset = record.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        "queryset": queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "detail.html", context)
```

Also note, my main is in home.html and not index.html. I wrote that by mistake

Comment: What is your STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in settings.py?

Comment: I am not sure where the STATIC_ROOT is, but the STATIC_URL is: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Ok, then please in the browser switch to source code and check how {% static .... %} tag is translated.

Comment: Do you mean I should go to "inspect" and there type in the console  {% static .... %} ?

Comment: No just something like "display source code"  in your browser menu... just to see the pure html code

Comment: When you say "browser menu", do you mean go to inspect on my web page? Isn't the code in my home.html file the pure html code?